# Number of google pages hits as a function of time

Tags: search, popularity

In each search in Google one can see number of google pages found.
Is it possible to find what was this number in the past?

Answer (score 1):

Best what you can try is [Google Zeitgeist](http://www.google.com/press/zeitgeist/). It doesn't give amount of found pages, but it gives insights of popularity of keywords, example: ["stackoverflow"](http://trends.google.com/trends?q=stackoverflow). You can also check the popularity of a website, example: [stackoverflow.com](http://trends.google.com/websites?q=stackoverflow.com).

No other Google services comes to mind for your particular purpose.

Answer (score 0):

No this number is not available. You could run the query and parse the Google results to capture the information, but I read the terms of use before you try to do that. In most case it will be against the terms of usage to do something like that.